# How to use SNI correctly? (Two Different Nginx SNI Writing Style)

Tags: nginx, sni

What's the difference between these two different SNI writing styles? Could someone judge their differences from principle, performance, and so on?

**Style1**

```
stream{
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $backend_name{
        A.example.com A;
        B.example.com B;
    }
    upsteam A{
        server 127.0.0.1:10086
    }
    upsteam B{
        server 127.0.0.1:10087
    }
}

http{
    server{
        listen 10086 ssl http2;
        server_name A.example.com
        ...
    }
}
```

**Style2**

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
    server_name A.example.com;
    ...
}
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
    server_name B.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from the question that you're trying to listen on 443 port for different hostnames. Requests coming with hostname `A.example.com` should get forwarded to `127.0.0.1:10086` while with hostname `B.example.com` would go to `127.0.0.1:10087`. Let me explain what's happening behind the scenes in both styles.

**Style 1**

> `stream` block lets you load balance over TCP/UDP. The [ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html) module lets you extract information from the request without ssl/tls termination. You're using `map` so connections coming as `A.exammple.com` set `A` in the variable `$backend_name` while those coming as `B.example.com` set `B` in the variable `$backend_name`. Based upon your `upstream` blocks the requests either get forwarded to `127.0.0.1:10086` or `127.0.0.1:10087`. Since there is an http block with server blocks listening on port 10086 and 10087 respectively, it creates a new connection every time fulfilling those requests. The ssl termination is also happening inside the http block.

**Style 2**

> Both server block are listening over 443 and depending on the hostname of the request it either goes through one of the `server` blocks. The ssl termination is happening before the request goes to ports where the application is actually running.

Both styles are good to achieve this but personally I'd prefer `Style 2` as the ssl termination is handled before the forwarding of the requests. Additionally, in `Style 1` there's an extra connection created which is a slight performance overhead, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer made me understand the SSL aspect of Nginx better.